# using 'by()' descriptive statistics are calculated in groups

Tags: r, statistics

```r
mtcars
vars <- c('mpg','hp','wt')
dstats <- function(x)(c(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)))
by(mtcars[vars],mtcars$am,dstats)
```

why return the error that Objects cannot be changed to a 'double' type

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using `aggregate` here is more appropriate :

```
aggregate(mtcars[vars], list(mtcars$am), dstats)

#  Group.1 mpg.mean   mpg.sd  hp.mean    hp.sd  wt.mean    wt.sd
#1       0 17.14737  3.83397 160.2632  53.9082 3.768895 0.777400
#2       1 24.39231  6.16650 126.8462  84.0623 2.411000 0.616982
```

---

`by` passes dataframe into the function so you need to modify your `dstats` function such that it handles dataframes and takes `mean` and `sd` for each column

```
dstats <- function(x) c(mean= colMeans(x),sd = sapply(x, sd))
by(mtcars[vars],mtcars$am,dstats)

#mtcars$am: 0
# mean.mpg   mean.hp   mean.wt    sd.mpg     sd.hp     sd.wt 
# 17.14737 160.26316   3.76889   3.83397  53.90820   0.77740 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#mtcars$am: 1
#  mean.mpg    mean.hp    mean.wt     sd.mpg      sd.hp      sd.wt 
# 24.392308 126.846154   2.411000   6.166504  84.062324   0.616982
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(am) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(vars), list(mean = mean, sd =sd))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     am mpg_mean hp_mean wt_mean mpg_sd hp_sd wt_sd
#  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     17.1    160.    3.77   3.83  53.9 0.777
#2     1     24.4    127.    2.41   6.17  84.1 0.617
```